# UWP programming - Can't get SMS store

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, windows-10-mobile

I'm the new one in `C#` and `UWP` development and I'm trying to create an app for win-mobile 10.
One of the tasks of this app is reading SMS messages.

On one of my `xaml` pages I use this code:

```
public sealed partial class TileSettings : Page
{
    public TileSettings()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();            
        GetMessages();
    }

    public async Task GetMessages()
    {
        ChatMessageStore store = await ChatMessageManager.RequestStoreAsync();
    }
}
```

Problem appears when I call the `ChatMessageManager.RequestStoreAsync()` function. The function is called but never returns any value and never exits from this function.

I have not a special permissions of Microsoft
as a developer. Can I use this function?

I'm trying to use Google and Stackoverflow search and found code like this with `RequestStoreAsync()` function, but it seems that no one ever faced this particular problem

May be I have logical error in the code and don't know how to use async functions in c# :)

Waiting for your comments about this behavior.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to need Company account. Please check it out below URL what are the benefits

https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations

Answer (score 0):

I found a problem.
There is UnauthorizedAccessException in this function.
I coudn't see this exception cause call of this task is incorrect.

I try use this code:

```
 public TileSettings()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

            Task.Run(() => GetMessages(), cts.Token);
        }

        private async void GetMessages()
        {
            ChatMessageStore store;
            store = await ChatMessageManager.RequestStoreAsync();

            var List = store.GetMessageReader();
        }
```

and caught this exception.

Do I need a special permissions to use this function to get sms messages?